# find redirect url

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect, iframe

I am using an `iframe` in my page to display content from an external website, but sometimes the iframe redirects a whole page to a new location, and this causes unwanted things on my website.

Is it possible to find the page where the `iframe` is going to redirect my website? if so, give me a basic example on how to find this redirection address. I would like to open this address in a new tab, because information from this address may be useful for my users.

**www.b.com [ abstract code ] :**

```
if(somethingHappens) window.top.location.href = "http://google.com";
```

**www.a.com [ abstract code ]:**

```
<!-- code -->
  <iframe src="http://www.b.com"></iframe>
<!-- code -->
```

**Expected Result [ abstract code ]:**

```
if(pageIsBeingRedirected) {
  stopRedirection();
  var url = findRedirectAddres(); // expected : http://google.com
  window.open(url, "_blank");
  return;
}
```

Comment: please provide some HTML on this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are redirecting to external sites then you can't track the iframe URL but you can get only what's in the iframe `src` value.

**Example,**

http://jsfiddle.net/CDwQK/1/

What you are looking will work only if `parent` and `iframe` shares same domain. It won't work if different domains.